# How to get values from a line in perl

Tags: perl

I'm still very new in perl and I wanted to  get numbers from a line and check if they are even when greater than 10 but I'm stuck at where I have to get the values from a line. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the diamond operator or [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @numbers = split ' ', <>;
for my $number (@numbers) {
    print "$number is even.\n" if $number > 10
                               && $number % 2 == 0;
}
```

- [split](http://p3rl.org/split) turns the input string like `12 13 14` into a list of numbers (12, 13, and 14).
- `%` is the modulo operator. Even numbers have the remainder of 0 when divided by 2.